# SQL Update row based on column index

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm using DataTables and jEdtiable to update my SQL database based on user entry.

The data passed to my PHP file is:

---

row_id = The data from the ID column in the HTML table, also the primary key in my SQL database.

column = The index of the column which has been edited

value = The new value to be updated on the table

---

I need to update the table using an SQL query, however I can't figure out a way to use the column index in the query, to update the correct row/column?

Comment: show or add your sample code after then we can suggest you specifically :) thank you

Comment: @code360 What else would you need other than the variable names? For things like the table names you could just advise using placeholders. There's not any other code which affects the problem I'm having with updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to map the column index to a column name. There are a couple of different ways you can do this mapping:

1. **Statically**. In your PHP code on the server, store an array that looks something like this:

   ```
   $columnMap = array(0 => 'column_1_name', 1 => 'column_2_name');
   ```

   Then use that array like so to figure out the column name to use in your SQL query:

   ```
   $columnName = $columnMap[$column]; // where $column is the column index passed to the PHP file.
   ```

   Finally, use the column name and value in your update SQL query. Make sure to properly escape the value to prevent SQL injection.

   The downside of this approach is that if you change the database table structure, you must also update the array in your code. This limitation goes away if you can use the second method described below.
2. **Dynamically**. Depending on what you are using to connect to your database (PDO, some DB framework, etc.), there should be methods that will return the structure of the table in the database. You can use these methods to retrieve the column names for a table, in order, and create the column map array dynamically.